# $2^{\sin(x) + \cos(y)} = 1$ , $16^{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(y)} = 4$ (system of equations)

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

My progress so far:

$2^{\sin(x) + \cos(y)} = 1$

$16^{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(y)} = 4$

||||||||||||||||||||

$\sin(x) + \cos(y) = 0$

$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(y) = \frac12$

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm not sure how to continue. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps.

Comment: You are on the right track. You used injectivity of the exponential function to make these conclusions. You meant $\sin ^2x + \cos ^2y = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\sin x + \cos y = 0$. Then
$$\sin ^2x + \cos ^2y = (\sin x + \cos y) ^2 -2\sin x\cos y = -2\sin x\cos y. $$
Thus we have left to consider
$$\begin{cases} \sin x + \cos y = 0 \\ \sin x\cos y = -\frac{1}{4} \end{cases} $$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation you get 
$$\sin x = -\cos y$$
Substituting that in the second equation, you get,
$$\dfrac12=\sin^2x+\cos^2y =2\sin^2x\\
\implies \cos2x = 1-2\sin^2x =\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3\\
\implies 2x = 2n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3\\
\implies \boxed{x = n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi6}\hspace{1cm}n\in\mathbb Z$$
or you could have directly got that using the fact that $$\sin^2x=\sin^2\dfrac\pi6\implies x=n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi6$$

Similarly, for $y$, we have
$$\cos^2y = \cos^2\dfrac\pi3\\
\implies \boxed{y = n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3}\hspace{1cm}n\in\mathbb Z$$